Convert selected text to a specific font in Outlook 365 Windows message
I'm trying to accomplish exactly what was described in this post 2 years ago.
I entered the code in the VBA editor for Outlook, and added the macro to the toolbar:
Public Sub Consolas9()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Word.Selection
    On Error Resume Next

    Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
        If objItem.Class = olMail Then
            Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
            If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
                Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
                Set objWord = objDoc.Application
                Set objSel = objWord.Selection
                With objSel
                    .Font.Name = "Consolas"
                    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .Font.Size = 9
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

As in the OP, the code does not work as-is. I get this error on the first line of the macro:

The solution from @Eugene Astafiev, is to "add a COM reference to the Word object model to be able to use the Word object model in Outlook VBA macros."
However, in my VBA editor, on the Tools Menu, the option for References is grayed out?
How do I enable the References to add the Word object model?

SIDENOTE: It would be nice to rephrase the title of the post similar to your last sentence.

Is "References" always greyed out?  Typically that's not available while your code is paused during (eg) debugging but should be available after you press the "stop" button in the VB editor.
